# Firestore Rules and custom claim with variable keys

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I m looking for a way to secure my app using custom claim, but i had difficulty to access them in firestore rules.

My user can be employees of multiple (say 1 to 5) organizations.
I would like to had oganizationId(s) as key in the user custom claims and roles as value.

Like that:

```
claims: {
  "organisationId1":"admin",
  "organisationId2":"regularEmployee",
  "organisationId3":"regularEmployee"
}
```

Setting the claims via cloud function work well, but i can't find the way to access customs Claims with variable keys

exemple of Security Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {  
    match /organisations/{oid} {
      allow read: if request.auth.token[oid] == "regularEmployee";
      allow write: if request.auth.token[oid] == "admin";
   }
}
```

Hope it is possible it would be an easy way to restrict many-to-many relationship

Comment: Are you referring to some dictionary you set up on Firebase? Can you please share how the data is being stored in order to know the datatype?

Comment: I'm trying to do this same thing. It's not working for me. Did you find a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76233140/firestore-and-custom-claims-docid-not-interpreted-as-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the way to do it.

```
 rules_version = '2';
 service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /collection/{documentId} {
       allow read: if true;
       allow write: if request.auth.token.role in ['admin']
     }
 }
```

It take 'admin' as string and work perfectly fine

And custom claims are like:

```
claims: {
  role:"admin"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Net Ninja actually made [a video about this](https://youtu.be/C87Un2rIm2g) back in 2019 that I just stumbled on.

Basically you want to check for `request.auth.token.yourCustomClaim`. In my case it looks something like this:

```
match /orders/{record} {
  allow read, update, delete: request.auth.token.isAdmin == true;
}
```

Haven't tested it against string values, but I can't think why it wouldn't work. Let us know how it goes, I suppose :)