# Firestore and custom claims - docId not interpreted as a string?

Tags: firebase-security, common-expression-language

I am using custom claims to grant access to firestore. I have it set already on the user, like so.

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(
    userId, {[myId123]:true})
```

Now I'm trying to write a rule to allow access. Here's what I have written.

```
match /myCollection/{myDocId} {
  allow read, write: request.auth.token.myDocId;
}
```

The docId I'm trying to access is `myId123`, but it is giving me permission denied when I try to access it.

So I manually wrote the rule like so...

```
match /myCollection/{myDocId} {
  allow read, write: request.auth.token.myId123;
}
```

... and now I have access. Since this works, I'm thinking that it's not interpreting `myDocId` to be a variable, but shouldn't `myDocId` be interpreted as a string there? What am I missing. Why isn't this working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76241741/15389900 It work fine with this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of...

```
match /myCollection/{myDocId} {
  allow read, write: request.auth.token.myDocId;
}
```

... you specify the id like ...

```
match /myCollection/{myDocId} {
  allow read, write: request.auth.token[myDocId];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to make it work, same answer as: [Firestore Rules and custom claim with variable keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68079575/15389900)

```
rules_version = '2';
 service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /collection/{documentId} {
       allow read: if true;
       allow write: if request.auth.token.role in ['admin']
     }
 }
```

It take 'admin' as string and work perfectly fine

And custom claims are like:

```
claims: {
  role:"admin"
}
```